# How to select the most distant values from the mean of a vector

Tags: r, distance, mean

Suppose the vector

```
vector<-c( 0.096846906,  0.068149926, -0.019938431, -0.095515090, -0.109936195, -0.006755265, -0.207243555,  0.117235435, -0.036333873, -0.156043650, -0.334150484,
   0.141990040, -0.116270635,  0.079373531,  0.070359814,  0.090415147,  0.046807444, -0.024908308,  0.022005548,  0.015559027,  0.065343488,  0.039524657,
   0.077209216,  0.051124695,  0.076794957, -0.059121977,  0.071967601,  0.042357348,  0.039801927,  0.053932640, -0.036346802, -0.070258993, -0.105611663,
   -0.138738161, -0.044395825, -0.194363631, -0.127153662,  0.052912436,  0.163879916,  0.087960810,  0.005298789, -0.191104683,  0.113214756,  0.045232380)
```

with `mean=-0.007702101`. I want to select the values that are most further from the mean. Suppose the 10 most distant values from the mean for example.

I use this code to get the values that are most distant from the mean:

```
sort(abs(vector-mean(vector)))
```

So basically now I have a series of differences that are ordered. But i cannot find a way to get the values (from the data named: vector) for which the distance is highest (again the 10 most distant). I am sure this is something simple, but I am really stuck!

Comment: You mean something like `vector[which.max(abs(vector - mean(vector)))]`?

Comment: yes! but instead of selecting only one ...select the 10 most extreme (or distant if you may). Or even the 20 most extreme etc. *I should edit the question to make it clear!

Comment: Lots of ways...maybe `vector[head(order(abs(vector - mean(vector)), decreasing = TRUE), 10)]`

Comment: Yes! sorry for late reply!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways of doing that. Based on your example and requirements, you can do,

```
m <- 10
vector[head(order(abs(vector - mean(vector)), decreasing = TRUE), m)]
#[1] -0.3341505 -0.2072436 -0.1943636 -0.1911047  0.1638799  0.1419900 -0.1560437 -0.1387382  0.1172354  0.1132148
```

Which translates to:

- Take the absolute value of the difference of each value from the mean
- Order decreasing (starting from largest value). Order gives indices rather than actual values (as `sort` does)
- Take the first `m` values using `head`. An alternative is `[1:m]`
- Wrap the indices in your vector to get the actual `vector` values

Comment: With a `-` before `abs` you can get rid of `decreasing = TRUE`.

Comment: If someone was to use it for a dataset this could be expanded as well: `apply(data,2,function(x) x[head(order(abs(x - mean(x)), decreasing = TRUE), m)])`

Comment: @HerculesApergis Of course. However, If you have a data frame try and avoid the `apply(df, 2, ...))` as it coerces to matrix thus costing it on efficiency. Ususally `sapply` or `lapply` would do the job

Answer (score 1):

you can use dplyr:

```
vector%>%as_tibble()%>%mutate(dist_Mean = abs(value - mean(value) ))%>%arrange(desc(dist_Mean))%>%top_n(10)
```

Comment: very interesting `dplyr` case!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go is based on the *standard deviation* that is adjustable.

Suppose `mn <- mean(vector)` and `std <- sd(vector)`, then

```
d <- 1.5
vector[vector<(mn-d*std) | vector>(mn+d*std)]

#[1] -0.2072436 -0.3341505 -0.1943636  0.1638799 -0.1911047
```

By adjusting `d`, you decide how far do you want to go from the mean.

(`d=1` gives you those numbers that are farther than 1 standard deviation from the mean)